# The trackrevisions method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading

Tags: c#, revision

I hope someone can help me. I am a programing it in C#. When I use this track revisions funcion, I meet a exception message whose content is the trackrevisions method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading.

I seach some documents but I have not any solution. Could you help me? thanks.

```
Word.Document document = null;
Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
wordApp.Visible = true;
Word.Document wordDoc = word.Documents.Open((object)docName);
wordDoc.Activate();
oDocument = wordDoc;
oDocument.Activate();
oDocument.TrackRevisions = true
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the start up option for opening Word in reading view (mode) was enabled. To fix, open your Word document, go to File > Options > General. Find Startup options and uncheck the Open e-mail attachments and other uneditable files in reading view option.